# pagination is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am working in CodeIgniter. I want to create pagination for dynamic record. So I have write code like below:

```
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "employer/search_user";

    $config["per_page"] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';


    if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
    }
    else{
           $page = 1;
    }

    $query = "select sn.*,u.first_name,u.last_name,u.email,u.phone,group_concat(DISTINCT s.skill) as sk,group_concat(DISTINCT c.name) as ct from 
                users as u
                left join snapshot as sn on sn.user_id = u.user_id
                left join industry as ind on ind.ind_id = sn.industry
                left join city c ON(FIND_IN_SET(c.city_id, sn.current_location) > 0)
                left join skill s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.skill_id, sn.skill) > 0)
                where ".$where." u.group_id = 3 group by u.user_id limit ".$config["per_page"];
    $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->query($query);

    $row = count($data['users']);
    $config["total_rows"] = $row;
    $config['num_links'] = $row;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['main_content']="employer/search_user";
    $this->load->view('employer/template', $data);
```

Here, I got 3 records in page but pagination link is not display. I have include pagination library in constructor. I did not get anuthing in `$data["links"]` this variable.

So where I have to correct my code? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: $config["num_links"] is number of pagination link that will displayed. eg. 
$config['num_links'] = 3 then
prev 1 2 3 next,,,, if its 4 then prev 1 2 3 4 next

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your query. For example

```
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4; // This is the current page

$offset = 0;
if ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) != "") {
    $offset = $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']);
}

$limit = $config['per_page'];

$sql = "SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `table_name`.field_name = ?";

if($limit != "") {
    $sql .= "LIMIT $limit ";
}

if($offset != "") {
    $sql .= "OFFSET $offset";
}

$result = $this->db->query($sql, array($field_data));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For $config["total_rows"] = $row; 
You get only 3. Because You are setting limit in the query. 
Kindly write another query for total rows without limit.I think this will solve Your problem.

Below is my pagination code

```
  $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "crm/crm/contactmgmt/modid/" .  $modid;
    if($this->input->post('Search')=='Search'){
        $data['pn']=$data1['pn']=$this->input->post('sel_prod');
        //echo "hello";
    }
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Crm_model->record_count_unsubinst();
    $config["per_page"] = 6;
    $this->load->config('pagination');
    $config["uri_segment"] = 6;
    $config['enable_query_strings']='true';

    $data['activeTab'] = "View";

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(6)) ? $this->uri->segment(6) : 0;
    $data['query'] = $this->Crm_model->listUnsubscribedInstn($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["link"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"]=$data["link"];
    $data["cnt"]=$config["total_rows"];
    $data["sno"]=$this->uri->segment(6);
```